# Dual space of arbitrary direct sum is the direct sum of dual spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, direct-sum

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces. It is known that dual space of a finite direct sum is the finite direct sum of each dual space, that is,

$$(X \oplus Y)^* = X^* \oplus Y^*$$

where $X^*$ denotes dual space of $X$.

Can we generalize it to arbitrary direct sum, that is, 
$$\left(\bigoplus_{\alpha}X_{\alpha} \right)^* = \left( \bigoplus_{\alpha} X^*_{\alpha} \right)?$$

I have a feeling it can be done but I don't know how to do it exactly. Can anyone give some hints?

UPDATE: According to Matt's comment, the finite direct sum does not hold for finite dimensional spaces. Then what about the following?
$$(X \times Y)^* = X^* \times Y^*$$

Can the product above be generalized to arbitrary products?

Comment: Even for finite-dimensional vector spaces this fails. The dual of a countable direct sum has uncountable dimension. You would think that perhaps the sum could be replaced by a product, though.

Comment: What does $\bigoplus_\alpha X_\alpha$ mean?  What is its norm?

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks for the comment below...I'm glad to be educated more about Banach spaces.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the" direct sum or product of an infinite collection of Banach spaces.  There are many different inequivalent ways to define it.  See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+sum+of+Banach+spaces for a brief discussion.  In sufficiently nice cases, I believe that you can say that the dual of a certain direct sum is a different direct sum of the duals, but I'm not familiar with the details enough to write an answer at the moment.

Comment: In particular, I think it should be true that the dual of the $\ell^p$ direct sum is the $\ell^q$ direct sum of the duals for $1\leq p<\infty$ and $1/p+1/q=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the category $\mathbf{Ban}_1$ of Banach spaces with contractive linear operators we do have products ($\bigoplus_\infty$-sums) and coproducts ($\bigoplus_1$-sums). 
Even more we have an isomorphism
$$
\left(\bigoplus_1 X_\alpha\right)^*\underset{\mathbf{Ban}_1}{\cong}\bigoplus_\infty X^*_\alpha
$$
Unfortunately, it is **not true**, that
$$
\left(\bigoplus_\infty X_\alpha\right)^*\underset{\mathbf{Ban}_1}{\cong}\bigoplus_1 X^*_\alpha
$$
To get the intuition why the latter is not true recall that $\ell_\infty^*\not\cong\ell_1$.

Comment: What a bizarre notation. So $\bigoplus_\infty = \prod$? It's a bit misleading (at least for someone like me who doesn't deal with Banach spaces often) to write that as $\bigoplus$...

Comment: This notation is used to unify the zoo of norms on the sums of Banach spaces. The generic one is $\bigoplus_p$ where $1\leq p\leq+\infty$.